# Ошибка "Record, object or class type required" в Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Выдает ошибку "Unit1.Pas(43): Record, object or class type required". Курсор указывает на Count. Как написать код верно и в чем заключается ошибка?

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Randomize;
  ComboBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
  ComboBox2.ItemIndex := 0;
  ComboBox3.ItemIndex := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.ItemIndex := Random(ComboBox1.ItemIndex.Count);
  ComboBox2.ItemIndex := Random(ComboBox2.ItemIndex.Count);
  ComboBox3.ItemIndex := Random(ComboBox3.ItemIndex.Count);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в том, что `ItemIndex` имеет тип `Integer` и у него нету свойства `Count`.

А вот у свойства `ComboBox1.Items`, которое имеет тип `TStrins`, есть искомое вами свойство: `ComboBox1.Items.Count`.